# Button height rendering inconsistency in Firefox - why are input elements taller?

Tags: firefox, button, height

Consider the following two elements:

```html
<button type="submit" class="button">Test</button>
<a href="#" class="button">Test 2</a>
```

...which use the following style definition:

```css
.button {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24pt;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This produces two buttons beside each other with an equal height in Chrome. However, Firefox renders the button on the left with a height `1px` greater than the button on the right (the `<a>`):

[image]

<sup>(I've enlarged the image above by 2x.)</sup>

What do I need to do to get the two buttons to have the same height? It seems like the `font-size` is causing the problem - but I need that attribute.

---

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FfRPY/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Eureka!**

The solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10274054/193619) completely eliminates the height difference:

```
.button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code :

```
.button {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 24pt;
    line-height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

<a href="#" class="button">Test 2</a>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Test 2"/>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me - the buttons still have different heights.