# When I explicitly set the height for my textboxes, why is it being changed?

Tags: html, css

For some reason the `input` textboxes are not adhering to the explicit height I've used.  Why is this happening?  I tried looking at the differences in code using Firebug but its happening for some reason.  In firebug it shows `height` is `16px` with no explanation.

css

```
#login_form input[type=text],
#login_form input[type=password]{
  height:26px !important;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

html

```
<form method="post" id="login_form" >
  <input type="text" size="30">
  <input type="password" size="30">
</form>
```

firebug screenshot
[image: firebug screenshot]

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274016/firefox-bug-with-input-line-height-any-work-around/10274054#10274054

Comment: I think more code is needed to solve this. Although meanwhile you could make sure that the css for height is in the end of css file - could be that makes a difference. Or you could try adding the height directly in html for testing purposes to see if that works. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would also come handy.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem to me... http://jsfiddle.net/3fgz4/

Comment: Are you using any JS on the page that does anything to the input fields?

Comment: Are there any instances where the change wouldn't show in firebug? I can't debug it without Firebug telling me where this is happening.

Comment: No javascript is influencing this because I removed the js file to test this issue.

Comment: What is your doctype by the way?

Comment: I ask about the doctype because earlier, non XHTML doctypes will have this problem. If you use something more modern like <!DOCTYPE html> the problem should go away, though that could cause other formatting issue of course.

Comment: Jude that was the issue - The Doctype.  Can you post that as the solution? Thanks